# Can I access objects that are instantiated in a class from outside that class?

Tags: python

I want to do something like this:

```
class worker():
    def run(self):
        # Do something

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        worker_obj = worker()

main_obj = main()
main_obj.worker_obj.run()
```

Is something like this wrong/possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `worker_obj` as an attribute of the instance (`self`):

```
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_obj = worker()
```

Otherwise, you are simply creating a local variable within `__init__` that immediately goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the attribute to self to make it available to use outside the function. Currently you are creating a function variable and not an instance attribute. 
Change your class to below

```
class worker():
def run(self):
    # Do something

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_obj = worker()

main_obj = main()
main_obj.worker_obj.run()
```